# Split element of list on delimiter. Store original element as key and list of split substrings as value in hashmap

Tags: java, arrays, collections, hashmap

I have a list:
`"Cust_Gnrc_Activity","MRkt_Cust","Indivdl_GNRC_Acct", "Opty_Act"`

I would like to split each element of on the "_" and store the original element as the key of a hashmap and the split elements as the value.

Desired Result:
`{"Cust_Gnrc_Activity":["Cust","Gnrc","Activity"], "Mrkt_Cust":["Mrkt", "Cust"]}` etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using Stream API:

```
list.stream() // stream over List
        // split by "_" and convert it to List<String>
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> Arrays.asList(s.split("_"))));
```

For `HashMap<String, List<String>>`:

```
list.stream()
        .collect(HashMap::new,
                (hm, s) -> hm.put(s, Arrays.asList(s.split("_"))),
                (hm1, hm2) -> hm1.putAll(hm2));
```

Answer (score 1):

something along the lines of:

```
source.stream()
      .collect(toMap(Function.identity(), e -> e.split("_"))); // Map<String, String[]>
```

or if you want the values as a `List<String>`:

```
source.stream()
      .collect(toMap(Function.identity(), 
                       e -> Arrays.stream(e.split("_"))
                                  .collect(toList()))); // Map<String, List<String>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this one:

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
list.forEach(str -> result.put(str, Arrays.asList(str.split("_"))));
```

, output

```
{Opty_Act=[Opty, Act], MRkt_Cust=[MRkt, Cust], Indivdl_GNRC_Acct=[Indivdl, GNRC, Acct], Cust_Gnrc_Activity=[Cust, Gnrc, Activity]}
```